# Invalid expression term 'foreach'

Tags: c#, xml, object, serialization

I'm trying to initalize an object for serialization, the class object was created using xsd.exe. The individual properties can be initialised without issue but when trying to initialise an 'unbounded' XSD property i can't use a foreach loop to go over each value in an array and add that to the object:

```
        object[] test = new object[0];

        test[0] = "ring";

        export export = new export();

        export.info = new exportInfo 
        {
            dateandtimeofexport = DateTime.Now,
            duration = "10",
            planningsoftware = new exportInfoPlanningsoftware
            {
                name = "",
                major = "",
                minor = "",
                revision = "",
                build = ""
            },
           exporter = new exportInfoExporter
           {
               version = new exportInfoExporterVersion
               {
                    name = "",
                    major = "",
                    minor = "",
                    revision = "",
                    build = ""
               },
               module = new exportInfoExporterModule[]
               {
                   foreach(Object x in test)
                   {
                   new exportInfoExporterModule{name = x.name, major = x.major, minor = x.minor, revision = x.revision, build = x.build;}
                   }
               }
           }
        };
```

I think the main problem here is my understanding of exactly how to initialise an array of objects under the object class created from my XSD using XSD.exe, can anyone advise on how this might be done without the foreach loop?

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Your code is not valid c#. You cannot use `foreach` inside an array initializer.

```
// NOT VALID C# CODE!
module = new exportInfoExporterModule[]
{
    foreach(Object x in test)
    {
        new exportInfoExporterModule{name = x}
    }
}
```

This is not possible, because `foreach` is a *statement*, but the array intializer expects an *expression* that results in a `exportInfoExportedModule`.

What you can do instead is something like this:

```
module = test.Select(x => new exportInfoExporterModule{name = x}).ToArray()
```

---

**But note** that at the start of your code you create the array `test` with length `0` and then try to set `"ring"` as its *first* (of *zero*) elements! That gives an `IndexOutOfRangeException`. Initialize `test` like that:

```
object[] test = new object[] {"ring"};
```

Answer (score 3):

```
module = test.Select(t => new exportInfoExporterModule{name = t}).ToArray()
```

instead of

```
module = new exportInfoExporterModule[]
           {
               foreach(Object x in test)
               {
               new exportInfoExporterModule{name = x}
               }
           }
```

should do the trick. Learn some LINQ at it will get clear what happened here ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a loop within an initializer.

See if you can initialize the array *after* you've constructed the rest of the object:

```
export.info = new exportInfo 
{
        // ...
        version = new exportInfoExporterVersion
        {
            name = "",
            major = "",
            minor = "",
            revision = "",
            build = ""
        }
    }
};

export.info.exporter.module = new exportInfoExporterModule[test.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < test.Length; i++)
{
    export.info.exporter.module[i] = new exportInfoExporterModule
    {
        name = test[i].name,
        major = test[i].major,
        minor = test[i].minor,
        build = test[i].build,
        revision = test[i].revision
    };
}
```

Or, with LINQ:

```
export.info = new exportInfo 
{
        // ...
        version = new exportInfoExporterVersion
        {
            name = "",
            major = "",
            minor = "",
            revision = "",
            build = ""
        },
        module = test.Select(x => new exportInfoExporterModule
        {
            name = x.name,
            major = x.major,
            minor = x.minor,
            build = x.build,
            revision = x.revision
        }).ToArray()
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks BoltClock, I'm very new to this so stumbling around a bit. This looks like the solution but before me reading up on LINQ further could you advise on how i can use the LINQ method to create a new exportInfoExporterModule where exportInfoExporterModule has not just 'name' but 'name, version, major, minor' please?

Comment: @Dan Hall: The same way you've created a new exportInfoExporterVersion, though of course you'll need to change x to the actual value(s) you're serializing. You might want to edit your question to include the actual object(s) being serialized so we have some more concrete data to work with.

Comment: thanks, i updated the code in my question slightly to show what I'm trying to attempt. What i don't understand is with the LINQ example what does the x signify? I'm wondering how this example can be expanded to create a exportInfoExporterModule object with the other properties.

Comment: Tried it, i imagine this is the way forward:

                   module = test.Select(x => new exportInfoExporterModule
                   {
                       name = x.name,
                       major = x.major, 
                       minor = x.minor, 
                       build = x.build, 
                       revision = x.revision 
                   }).ToArray()

Comment: @Dan Hall: You got it.

Answer (score 1):

The first two lines of your code will result in a runtime exception, as you're attempting to put a value in a zero-length array.

```
object[] test = new object[0];
test[0] = "ring";
```

> Run-time exception (line -1): Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Here is a [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HgCrIy) to show that.

Iterating over an array via a `foreach` is totally fine! But the issue is really that the loop is within an object initializer. This is not permitted, instead use `Linq` with a `.Select` and `.ToArray()`.

```
module = test.Select(t => new exportInfoExporterModule { name = t })
             .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the array you want to assign before you create your exporter object.

Another way could be to use Linq to assign module. Something like 
`module = test.Select(x => new exportInfoExporterModule{name = x}).ToArray()`
should work.

Answer (score -1):

To be able to use a foreach you have to iterate on a container implementing interface IEnumerable.

It is not the case of a simple array. Just transform test in a List (List implements IEnumerable) and it should work.

```
List<object> test = new List<object>();
```

Comment: Or shorter again `foreach (Object x in test.ToList())`

Comment: Simple arrays most certainly can be iterated with `foreach`. It is stunning, not in a good way, that this answer got two upvotes. The OP's problem is that `foreach` is not allowed inside an array initializer, `= new exportInfoExporterModule[] { ... }`, not that `foreach` does not support arrays.

Comment: Thanks guys, but the issue here is that foreach can't be used whatsover in the context shown. It seems only the underlying class structure (created by xsd.exe) can be used and no operations are possible in this object initialization.